# Put every element from an array in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a json with some elements and on branch I have an array named cars

```
    for(var i=0;i<itemsArray;i++)
    {    
       $('.red').append('<p class="col-xs-2 no-padding text-format">' + item[i].cars + '</p>');
    }
```

How the array looks:

```
  "cars": ["dawdawd","wadwad","wadwad","wad"];
```

What I need is to put every element from this array on a paragraph like i'm using with append;

For example:

```
<p class="col-xs-2 no-padding text-format">dawdawd</p>
<p class="col-xs-2 no-padding text-format">wadwad</p>
```

**EDIT:**

Complete array:

```
 "description": "asdasd",
 "name": "geaaar",
 "shop": "http://google.com",
 "date": "2016-12-31T00:00:00.000Z",
 "cars": [
          "dawdawd",
          "wadwad",
          "wadwad",
          "wad"
        ],




  var itemsArray = data.data.my_Array.length; //length of the array
```

Comment: What is content of `itemsArray`? The `cars` array or json data?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `length` property in order to `iterate` array items.

```
for(var i=0;i<itemsArray.length;i++)
                       ^^^^^^^^
{    
   $('.red').append('<p class="col-xs-2 no-padding text-format">' + itemsArray[i].cars + '</p>');
}
```

Also, you can use `forEach` method which accepts as paramaeter a callback function.

```
itemsArray.forEach(function(item){
    $('.red').append('<p class="col-xs-2 no-padding text-format">' + item.cars + '</p>');
});
```

Comment: hi my romanian:). I'm using .length to iterate..but I have more elements..

Comment: You can use `forEach` method which accepts a callback function like a parameter.

Comment: Even better would be to use an iterator function, like [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and and not have to worry about `length` and `increment` and `get` value. jQuery even comes with the [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method, if your browser is that old.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var paras ='';
for(var i=0;i<itemsArray.length;i++) {
     paras += '<p>'+itemsArray[i]+'</p>';
}
```

After loop,

```
$('.red').html(paras);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
  "description": "asdasd",
  "name": "geaaar",
  "shop": "http://google.com",
  "date": "2016-12-31T00:00:00.000Z",
  "cars": [
    "dawdawd",
    "wadwad",
    "wadwad",
    "wad"
  ]
};

var $container = $(".red");
obj.cars.forEach(function(car) {   // for each car in obj.cars array
  $container.append("<p>" + car + "</p>"); // add the car as a paragraph inside the div .red
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="red"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `join` on the array.

```js
var obj = {
  "description": "asdasd",
  "name": "geaaar",
  "shop": "http://google.com",
  "date": "2016-12-31T00:00:00.000Z",
  "cars": [
    "dawdawd",
    "wadwad",
    "wadwad",
    "wad"
  ]
};

$('.red').append(obj.cars.length ? '<p>' + obj.cars.join('</p><p>') + '</p>' : '');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="red"></div>
```